# Clean Architecture Python Example: How to implement a Usecase/Interactor saving Data to a Database

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture

I am struggling with the clean architecure. I have constructed a minimal example of how a usecase/interactor could talk to the database without being dependent on it:

The use case:

```
class SaveDatatoDBUseCase:
def __init__(self, AbstractDB):
    self.db = AbstractDB

def execute(self):
    self.db.save()
```

The gateway:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod    
class AbstractDB(ABC):

def __init__(self, value):
    pass

@abstractmethod
def save(self):
        pass
```

The Implementation for the Database:

```
class DBImplemtation(AbstractDB):
def __init__(self):
    pass

def save(self):
   print("INSERT INTO TABLE WHERE ...")
```

Wiring it altogether:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
dbImpl = DBImplemtation()
save_to_db_Usecase = SaveDatatoDBUseCase(dbImpl)
save_to_db_Usecase.execute()
```

yields to:

INSERT INTO TABLE WHERE ...

Is this how the communcation works between the UseCase/Interactor and the Database or I am I missing something here? I added a picture to clarify what I wanted to achieve with the code.

Can someone please confirm, whether this is a good minimal approach and if not, where I got this wrong or even what could be improved. Thank you in advance.

[image: This is what I wanted to achieve]

Comment: You are in the right path. What you named Gateway is often named Repository, Store or DAO, but this doesn't change the overall picture. *UseCase -> Data Access Abstractation <- Data Access Implementation*